# Can Power BI insert a row which has special format?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I am new for Power Query, I want to insert a row, but this row has different data format. I used :

```
Table.InsertRows(_, Table.RowCount(_),{[DATE="01/01/1990", MAINACCOUNT= 00001, AMOUNT=0,  Financial Year=""]})
```

But the DATE, I want it to be date format, the AMOUNT I want it to be number format, anyone know how to do it?

Comment: You say the row has different data formet. In relation to what? You exiesting data of a different row or in relation to the columns in your table? If it is the latter, you will need to format your column befor the insert row step.

Comment: Please provide full sample data for your starting point and expected output.

Comment: All the rows in a given column will have the same datatype.  So your new row will assume the same data type as the columns already existing in the table. Please provide more detail as to exactly what you are trying to do.